# what is a "Self programming language"

Tags: programming-languages, smalltalk, selflanguage

I am learning SmallTalk now using Squeak4.1. I use Squeak by Example  as a tutorial, Here I countered a delema,  " Morphic was developed by  ... for the Self programming language "
Can anybody give some hints on the meaning of self programming language?Do it means smtalltalk is a self programming language?

Comment: Next time, please try to look around for the answer by yourself before asking.  In this case, the answer can easily be found here:  http://www.google.com/search?q=self+programming+language.  Good luck with your study.

Comment: http://selflanguage.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Self](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_programming_language) is an object-oriented programming language.

When I first read your question I though the same as I think you are - that the language programmed itself. However, the capitalised 'Self' should have given it away. :)

Comment: thanks frind:) Self means a kind of object-oriented programing language. I got it:)

Comment: Not really. Self is the **name** of one particular object-oriented programming language.

Answer (score 3):

Self is an object-oriented programming language developed at Sun Microsytems.
Check out: http://labs.oracle.com/self//language.html

Answer (score 3):

This is cute, considering how ***the*** [*Self* programming language](http://www.selflanguage.org/) is also ***a*** self programming language!

Self is a programming language in which Morphic was devised as the model for user interface. Squeak adapted it from there, with the bit of pain it implied migrating from a prototypes based language to a class based one.

BTW, Smalltalk is a self programming language too! Smalltalk, as Self, is defined by itself (in terms of more Smalltalk and a few VM primitives).

Comment: Nice answer! Better than the accepted one, objectively, (haha) but then you were a bit late. :)

Comment: Yeah, 2 yrs late is hard to beat! But i hope people will keep looking for the sexiest language ever!